# Swift. Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Tags: swift, generics

I want to create one method for mapping object. So i have the method like this:

```
func testDecode<T: Decodable>(from: DocumentSnapshot) -> T? {
    do {
        return try from.data(as: T.self)
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

And im using it like this:

```
let test = testDecode(from: document.data) as? TestModel
```

but i have an error: `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred` cant understand why i have this error, please give me advice

Comment: Voted down for hiding the error. This function is just the `try?` keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't try to cast the value, but rather annotate `test` as `TestModel?` to let the compiler infer the generic type `T` as `TestModel`.

```
let test: TestModel? = testDecode(from: document.data)
```

Comment: `: TestModel?` is the same as `as TestModel?`. The question mark just needs to move for equivalence.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but have the same error `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`

Comment: @vetaney915 please update your question with the your definition of `DocumentSnapshot` and specifically its `data(as:)` method, because that means the issue will be inside there